Data Fetch Fails in Production Environment for React App Hosted on Subdomain
I have a WordPress website hosted on Hostinger, and I've created a subdomain to test my React website deployment.
In my local development environment using VS Code, the data fetch works perfectly with the following URL:
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/blogs/';
However, when I deploy the React app to the subdomain on Hostinger, the data fetch fails, even though the rest of the website (e.g., navbar) loads correctly. As a result, features such as adding or deleting blogs also fail.
Here's a summary of the problem:
Local Development: Data fetch works with http://localhost:8000/blogs/
Production (Hostinger Subdomain): Data fetch fails
Additionally, the data is placed in a JSON file (db.json) inside a data folder.
I suspect it might be related to the API URL configuration or CORS issues, but I am not entirely sure.
I am new to React and have almost no experience with backend development, so I apologize if this question sounds foolish or too basic.
Can someone help me understand why the data fetch fails in the production environment and how to fix it?
Additional Info:
The React app is hosted on a subdomain.
The rest of the React app loads without issues.
The API server is running and accessible in the production environment.
Thank you in advance!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are there any error messages?
